# How can I work only with siblings in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, frontend

How can I accomplish this, let's say I have this checklist created dynamically in htlm. What I want is if I create exact same checklist with .append() and press button add-item it will trigger only that button which is clicked not both of them?

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" />
   <label for="check1"><span class="chk-text">Checklist One<span></label>
     <br>
   <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
   <label for="check2"><span class="chk-text">Checklist two<span></label>
     <br>
   <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check">
   <label for="check3"><span class="chk-text">Checklist three<span></label>
   </div> <!-- END OF CHECKBOX -->
   <button class="add-item" type="button">Add</button>
</div> <!-- END OF ADD-ITEM -->

<div class="checkbox">
   <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" />
   <label for="check1"><span class="chk-text">Checklist One<span></label>
     <br>
   <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
   <label for="check2"><span class="chk-text">Checklist two<span></label>
     <br>
   <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check">
   <label for="check3"><span class="chk-text">Checklist three<span></label>
   </div> <!-- END OF CHECKBOX -->
   <button class="add-item" type="button">Add</button>
</div> <!-- END OF ADD-ITEM -->
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-item', function(){
    $('.checkbox').append('<br><input id="check' + idCounter + '" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="check' + idCounter + '"><span class="chk-name">' + name + '</span></label>');
  });
```

How can I append new checklist only in a div which I selected not in both.

Comment: Is there any js-code related to your question? If so please feel free to add it. I don't get what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `add-item` buttons are inside the same parent containers you want the checkboxes to go into, you can target them like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-item', function(){
   $(this).parent().append('<br><input id="check' + idCounter + '" type="checkbox" name="check"><label for="check' + idCounter + '"><span class="chk-name">' + name + '</span></label>');
```

});

Actually - your HTML looks invalid? You have closing tags for 'add-item' but no opening tags that match. So your structure may be different than what I thought. You may need to go up two levels of `parent` if that's the case, but the idea's the same. As long as your buttons and the place you want to add the checkbox share a parent somewhere, this approach works. If they don't share a parent (or share it with all the other checkboxes), try other ways of traversing the DOM - siblings, `$().nearest()`, etc.